# add a checkbox for menu items in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to add a checkbox for menu items from `Appearance -> Menus -> Menu structure -> Item`. If the checkbox is checked, the `target="_blank"` attribute is added to the `a` tag.

I want something like this screenshot:

[image]

This is a rendering of the menu in my case:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu([
   'theme_location' => 'primary',
   'container'      => '',
   'walker'         => new description_walker(),
]); ?>

class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null, $id = 0)
    {
        $title = trim($item->title);
        $classes = (!empty($item->classes)) ? implode(" ", $item->classes) : '';
        $button = (!empty($item->classes) && in_array('menu-item-has-children',
                $item->classes)) ? '<span class="button-show">+</span>' : '';    
        $output .= "<li class='" . $classes . "'>";
        $output .= '<a href="' . $item->url . '">';
        $output .= $title;
        $output .= '</a>';
        $output .= $button;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show this option from the "**Screen Options**"

[image]

And then you have it
[image]

Edit: So I see that you are using a custom walker for your navigation - **new description_walker()**

In the code of this custom walker, you should usually have something like

```
$attributes = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
$attributes .= !empty($item->target) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
$attributes .= !empty($item->xfn) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
$attributes .= !empty($item->url) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';
```

Those are attributes based on selected options from the admin panel, for example the checkbox that you are referring to.

And then, those attributes are being attached to the link like that

```
<a' . $attributes . '>
```

This is the default way of having that functionality in a custom walker. You can check this example https://github.com/sarn1/example-wordpress-menu-walker/blob/master/wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php or search for another one that adds attributes to the link based on selected choices from the admin panel. They will be mostly the same, just with a different coding style.

Edit: Here is your complete code

```
<?php wp_nav_menu([
   'theme_location' => 'primary',
   'container'      => '',
   'walker'         => new description_walker(),
]); ?>

class description_walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = null, $id = 0)
    {
        $title = trim($item->title);
        $attributes = !empty($item->attr_title) ? ' title="' . esc_attr($item->attr_title) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->target) ? ' target="' . esc_attr($item->target) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->xfn) ? ' rel="' . esc_attr($item->xfn) . '"' : '';
        $attributes .= !empty($item->url) ? ' href="' . esc_attr($item->url) . '"' : '';
        $classes = (!empty($item->classes)) ? implode(" ", $item->classes) : '';
        $button = (!empty($item->classes) && in_array('menu-item-has-children',
                $item->classes)) ? '<span class="button-show">+</span>' : '';    
        $output .= "<li class='" . $classes . "'>";
        $output .= '<a' . $attributes . '>';
        $output .= $title;
        $output .= '</a>';
        $output .= $button;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. yes, I mapped the checkbox, but the cheked checkbox does not add the `target="_blank"` attribute to the `a` tag. Why could this be happening?

Comment: are you using a custom code for the navigation and links in your theme? Because it does work with the default themes from WordPress.

Comment: I've updated my question. At the bottom after the word **EDIT**. Please take a look.

Comment: I updated my answer as well. @s.kuznetsov

Comment: Thanks a lot, but it's not quite clear to me where I should add this code.

Comment: can you find the code from the new description_walker() class and paste it in your question?

Comment: I added the code to the question

Comment: Updated my answer as well. This should work